# Spark streaming from kafka to elastic search index

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to index Kafka inputs into elasticsearch using Spark Streaming.

The messages in kafka are like this :

"Tom 34 happy Paris"

I would like to define in Spark Streaming the structure in order to index this message in elasticsearch :

{ Name: "Tom",
  Age: 34,
  Status: "happy",
  City: "Paris }

I've read about RDD transformations but couldn't find how to define the keys of the values.

I need your help.

Below My code which only do a word counting of the message received from Kafka:

```
package com.examples

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._


object MainExample {

def main(arg: Array[String]) {

var logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())

val jobName = "MainExample"

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(jobName)    
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))

val zkQuorum = "localhost:2181"
val group = ""
val topics = "test"
val numThreads = 1

val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_,numThreads.toInt)).toMap
val lineMap = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap)
val lines = lineMap.map(_._2)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val pair = words.map( x => (x,1))
val wordCounts = pair.reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(10), Seconds(2), 2)
wordCounts.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JavaRDD<Map<String,String>> result = input.map(new Function<String, Map<String, String>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> call(String v1) throws Exception {
            Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<>();
            int i=0;
            for(String val : v1.split(" ")){
                ret.put("key"+i++, val);
            }
            return ret;
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Atul, I need an example in Scala Language please.